# Cardinality of the product of countably many sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I found the exact question here on stack exchange, but the answers there aren't thorough enough for me to understand them. Any help would be appreciated.

---

[Here is the original question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142502/cardinality-of-a-product-of-countable-many-sets)

---

Here is the question (so you don't have to follow the link):

Let $\{A_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{Z_+}}$ be a countable collection of sets. Let $B = \displaystyle \prod_{i\in \mathbb{Z_+}}A_i$ be the Cartesian product of the collection. Prove that if every set of the collection $\{A_i\}_{i\in \mathbb{Z_+}}$ contains two distinct elements, then $B$ is numerically equivalent to $\mathbb{R}$, that is, $|B|=|\mathbb{R}|$

In this instance, I am assuming the axiom of choice.

I couldn't understand the answers listed in the link above. If anyone could elaborate on the answers or explain it in a different way I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Are you familiar with Cantor's Diagonlization argument?

Comment: Vaguely, yes. It's a way to "count" the elements of an infinite set.

Comment: More specifically, it is often used in proof by contradiction.

Comment: @Clayton I don't think the Diagonalization argument is enough here... OP has to prove an equality, not just an inequality...

Comment: @5xum: You are right! It is late; I was thinking only of proving the set was not countable.

Comment: The statement is inaccurate. Taking each $A_i$ to be $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$ will satisfy the assumption that each set contains two distinct elements; but the size of the product has to be much larger than $|\Bbb R|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

It's safe to just assume that $A_i = \{0,1\}$ for each $i$. Then, each element of $B$ is simply a series of ones and zeros.

**Hint 2:**

Every element in $[0,1]$ (which is equipotent to $\mathbb R$) can be written almost uniquely in binary notation as $0.a_1a_2a_3\dots$, where $a_i\in\{0,1\}$.

Comment: I don't understand hint 2. Sorry for pestering people about something that was already answered... but nothing in the book or online is making sense right now.

Comment: @user2925 Do you know about binary notation?

Comment: I do, and I know how to convert bases and what not... I'm quite familiar with binary (as I have to be for my degree) but I don't see how this helps with the numerical equivalence to $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @user2925 OK, do you understand the following points:

1) in order to prove numerical equivalence, you need to find a **bijection** from your set to $\mathbb R$.
2) Because $[0,1]$ is equipotent to $\mathbb R$, you only need a bijection from your set to $[0,1]$
3) Every element of your set can be written as $(a_1,a_2, a_3, a_4,\dots)$ where each $a_i\in\{0,1\}$
4) Every element in $[0,1]$ can be written as $0.a_1a_2a_3a_4\dots$, where each $a_i\in\{0,1\}$.

Comment: I think I see where you're going with this... I can "construct" a function that takes the binary string and outputs something unique on the domain [0,1], correct? And since $|[0,1]| = |\mathbb{R}|$ I can conclude that $|B| = |\mathbb{R}|$. Right?

Comment: @user2925 That's the general idea. You still have to deal with element like $0.01111111111111...$ which is equal to $0.1$ (in the same way as $0.99999999...$ is equal to $1$), so you still have some work to do. However this part shouldn't be that hard and I think it's better if you try to solve it on your own.